# Handsontable number format

Tags: handsontable

I have an issue when using Handsontable.
I'm using version 0.30.1 and al trying to change the currency symbol fro $ to € (very basic use case).
I am using the handsontable.full.js file which contains as far as I understand the different additional plugins, incl. numbro.js responsible for number formatting.
However, when i use the following code

```
    var hot_produit = new Handsontable(container_produit, {
              data: data_produit,
              rowHeaders: false,
              colHeaders:false,
              columns: [
                  {data: 'text1'},
                  {data: 'text2'},
                  {data: 'text3'},
                  {data: 'sales1',type: 'numeric', format: '0,0.00 $', language:'fr-FR'}
                 ],
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown culture : fr-FR
```

It seems that the language library is not available (although I checked and the language.js file and folder with different files, incl. fr-FR.min.js are present in the dist folder).

Note: when removing the `language:'fr-FR'` part, the code works perfectly, but formats the table with $ signs

Thanks a lot

Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

You have to include "languages.js" provided with numbro. Its not automatically included with handsontable.full.

```
<script src="(handsontable path)/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="(your path)/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
<script src="(handsontable path)dist/numbro/languages.min.js"></script>
```